# who were the amateur mathematicians had won the field medal?

Tags: math-history

Who were the   amateur mathematicians  had  won the  field medal?

I search the field medal  winners. I  didn't find any single amateur mathematician who won the field medal. All are from academics background (mostly  from Princeton University.)

I think no amateur mathematicians had won the field medal.

Comment: Cedric Villani can be considered as an amateur mathematician, since he is now a politician... (don't take this too seriously)

Comment: One reason for this is that doing fields-medal-level work takes an insane amount of time and effort over many years or decades. It is extremely hard to spend this much time on research math if it is not your job, so there are ~0 amateur mathematicians who are producing new research in very technical areas of math.

Comment: It used to be (some time ago) that almost every mathematician was an amateur without a lot of formal university training. Euclid’s Elements was a textbook for mathematicians for about 2000 years. Euclid was an amateur mathematician - perhaps he have would have been awarded with an (ancient) Fields medal, if this had existed.

Comment: What is an "amateur mathematician?"  Would a physicist be of amateur status?  If so, then Ed Witten would qualify.

Comment: A broader question might be what amateur mathematicians have made any significant progress in mathematics since 1936, the year of the first Fields Medal. It is much harder to be an amateur mathematician in the modern era.

Comment: Neither Cedric Villani nor Ed Witten are amateurs in any sense of the word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One who is not a professional mathematician is Edward Witten, who is a physicist.

Comment: Well, theoretical physics is almost a branch of mathematics. That’s about as broad a definition as you can get for “amateur mathematician.”